# Modelling shared error states for use in explicit error declarations via Eithers

Tags: scala, either

How can I manage error states that may be shared across multiple type hierarchies?

Consider an application that manages a database of people. It has a `Person` model and two methods in the API:

```
case class Person(name: String)

def createPerson(name: String): Either[CreateFailure, Person]
def renamePerson(newName: String): Either[RenameFailure, Person]

sealed trait CreateFailure
object CreateFailure {
  case object PersonAlreadyExists extends CreateFailure
  case object NamesCantHaveEmojis extends CreateFailure
}

sealed trait RenameFailure
object RenameFailure {
  case object CanOnlyRenameMinors extends RenameFailure
  case object NamesCantHaveEmojis extends RenameFailure
}
```

Each method can fail in its own unique way, but each method can *also* fail in the *same* way via `NamesCantHaveEmojis`. In the above trivial example I have two copies of this error state and this is triggering my code smell sensors. What if I need extend `NamesCantHaveEmojis` with new functionality, do I add it to both? Or have them each implement a common `trait EmojiUtils` that provides the shared functionality?

[Scala 3's Union Types](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/union-types.html) seem like they would fit the bill, but we haven't adopted Scala 3 yet.

```
type CreateFailure = PersonAlreadyExists | NamesCantHaveEmojis
type RenameFailure = CanOnlyRenameMinors | NamesCantHaveEmojis
```

It seems like many folks in the Scala community have been using `Either` for explicit error handling for a while now so I can only assume someone else has come across this scenario and found a good solution.

How can I share error states across multiple type hierarchies in Scala 2?

Comment: You can have `NameCantHaveEmojis` extend both traits. What I would do would be to have all the errors in the same file called `errors.acala` contained in a object called `errors` _(emulating a package)_ and then putting all errors there. If you like to have the specific errors inside the companion objects of their parent trait you can have a `val` that does the aliasing.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `NameCantHaveEmojis` as object and extend two or more traits:

```scala
sealed trait CreateFailure
object CreateFailure {
  case object PersonAlreadyExists extends CreateFailure
}

sealed trait RenameFailure
object RenameFailure {
  case object CanOnlyRenameMinors extends RenameFailure
}

// you can extends here more than one trait using `with` keyword
case object NamesCantHaveEmojis extends CreateFailure with RenameFailure
```

and after you can use this error type in different `match` constructions:

```scala
val createError: CreateFailure = NamesCantHaveEmojis
createError match {
  case PersonAlreadyExists => println("PersonAlreadyExists")
  case NamesCantHaveEmojis => println("NamesCantHaveEmojis")
}
// NamesCantHaveEmojis printed

val renameError: RenameFailure = NamesCantHaveEmojis
renameError match {
  case CanOnlyRenameMinors => println("PersonAlreadyExists")
  case NamesCantHaveEmojis => println("NamesCantHaveEmojis") 
}
// NamesCantHaveEmojis printed
```

looks like `createError` and `renameError` are different failure types but they just one type and can be matched in different contexts.